# Keeping data private for an application

Tags: java, security, operating-system

Assuming that i have a piece of data that i want to keep private to an application running under a security context shared by a user, is it possible to keep data from the user in some way?

Say that i have, for example, a public key for a remote server that is used by the application and is stored on disk(In a file/database, whatever), is it possible to somehow keep users running the application from changing the public key (Short of hardcoding the value in the application)?

I don't see the problem being solved by encryption, since the user would be able to read the encryption key available to the application. The user would also be able to read the database credentials if the data is kept there.

Is it in any way possible to allow an application to keep a piece of data from other users/applications in the same security context, so that only the application can change it?

Comment: I tried rewording the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A desktop application usually runs in the security context of the user. This means that the application has access to resources (files/sockets/databases) that the user is allowed to access.

So if there are other applications, running in the same security context, they will have access to the same resources.

You can of course use encryption in your application to keep certain data private, but the encryption key used has to be stored either hard coded in the application (and applications running in the same security context always have read access to your executable or you would not be able to launch that app) or stored in the applications' configuration. This means that it may be difficult, but not impossible for other applications running in the same security context to find that encryption key.

So it's not really possible to keep data private from other applications running in the same security context.

Server applications typically do not run in the user's security context. So if all your server applications run under different accounts, it it possible to keep data private. But for applications running under the same account, the same same issues are there.